# NameNotFoundException throws by lookup() method but not in JSE API

Tags: java, jndi

According to JSE API, **javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup()** throws only **NamingException**. If any function throw a subclass exception then it also mentioned in API.
I was trying to find an object which is not available in directory Server, then lookup method throws an exception NameNotFoundException object but according to API it throws only NamingException object.
Tell me, why it throws NameNotFoundException object instead of NamingException object.
In my program two catch block are used,one for **NameNotFoundException** and second for **NamingException**.

Answer (score 0):

> According to JSE API, javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup() throws only NamingException.

Where does it say that?

> If any function throw a subclass exception then it also mentioned in API.

That is simply not true. There are numerous counter-examples. It isn't required to document every derived exception, and frequently Javadoc authors will confine themselves to the base exception.

`NameNotFoundException` extends `NamingException.` That explains it completely.